# issue with creating role and channel automatically from private message with bot

Tags: node.js, roles, channel, discord.js

Not sure how the create channel and create role isn't working inside the following code, towards the bottom. (EDIT: Nothing is sent to the console and nothing happens regardng the code. It is like it is entirely ignored.) This is a snippet from code that User A challenges User B. User B is messaged, alerting them that a challenge has been issued to them via a Private Message. If the challenge is accepted, I want the bot to 1)Make a role specifically for User A and User B named "User A vs User B" 2) take User A and User B and put them both into that new role and 3) Make a battlefield named "User A vs User B" inside a specific category inside the server the bot is on.

I am unsure if the problem lies in how the bot is trying to make the role and channel in a sever while the bot is talking to the user in a private message instead of on the server. I thought putting the "server" variable as the server ID would help but it doesn't seem to do anything after the accept message.

```html
// Awaits reply from user
if (message.channel.id === '541736552582086656') return target.send("Do you accept the challenge? Please reply with 'accept' or 'deny'.")
  .then((newmsg) => {
    newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
      max: 1,
      time: 150000,
      errors: ['time'],
    }).then((collected) => {
        // Grabs the first (and only) message from the collection.
        const reply = collected.first();
      
        if (reply.content === 'accept'){
          reply.channel.send(`You have ***accepted *** the challenge from ${challenger}. Please wait while your battlefield is made...`);
          message.author.send(`${target} has accepted your challenge! Please wait while the channel is made for your brawl...`)
/// Problems start here
          function createChannel(message){
            var server = "SERVER ID";
            var name = `${target} vs ${challenger}`;
            message.guild.createRole({
                role: {
                    name: `${target} vs ${challenger}`,
                    color: "#00fffa",
                    permissions: [] }
            }).then(role => {
                target.addRole(role, name)
                challenger.addRole(role, name)
                .catch(error => client.catch(error))
            }).catch(error => client.catch(error))
            server.createChannel(Name, name).then(
                (channel) => {
                    channel.setParent("CATEGORY ID")
          })
        } // problems end here
        } else if (reply.content === 'deny') {
          reply.channel.send("You have ***denied *** the challenge.") 
        } else {
          reply.channel.send("Your response wasn't valid.");
        }
      })
   })
}
```

I have been wondering if I need to go about making the channel and role in a different way since it is trying to be made from a private message and not inside the server..

Thanks for any and all help! I also apologize if I'm using stack overflow too much for problems like this... You guys are great at helping me see different ways to do things and what I'm doing wrong, so I am learning, but I don't want to feel like I'm abusing it too much.

Comment: what error do you have?

Comment: You told as what you expect, but in such a question you have to provide what you expect and then what happens currently

Comment: Nothing happens. The code works flawlessly up until the point I specified. There's no error codes or anything sent to the console. It is like the code is ignored entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the fact that you create a function called `createChannel` with the code to create a rol and channel, but you never call said function.

You can either call the function after you've declared it or (which is in my opinion better) you can remove the following lines

`function createChannel(message){`

`} // problems end here`

Comment: This fixed my issue perfectly! Thanks!